# jQuery use .load() to append data instead of replace

Tags: jquery

how can i have the functionality of `load()` except i want to append data instead of replace. maybe i can use `get()` instead but i want to just extract the `#posts` element from the loaded data

## UPDATE

when i do an `alert(data)` i get ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="posts">
    <div class="post"> ... </div> 
    ...
  <ul id="pageNav" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="page1.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.html">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="page5.html">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html" class="next">next</a></li>  
  </ul>
```

the full code can be found @ [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EmT33QKS)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no reason you can't extract the element you want using `$.get()`.

```
$.get('test.html',function(data) {
    var posts = $(data).find('#posts');
       // If the #posts element is at the top level of the data,
       //    you'll need to use .filter() instead.
       // var posts = $(data).filter('#posts');
    $('#container').append(posts);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

You perhaps didn't notice the code comments above, so I'm going to make it more explicit here.

If the `#posts` element is at the top of the hierarchy in `data`, in other words if it doesn't have a parent element, you'll need to use `.filter()` instead.

```
$.get('test.html',function(data) {
    var posts = $(data).filter('#posts');
    $('#container').append(posts);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments below, you seem to need `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

The reason is that you're passing in an entire HTML structure. When you do that, jQuery places the direct children of the `body` tag as the array in the jQuery object.

jQuery's `.filter()` filters against only the nodes in that array. Not their children.

jQuery's `.find()` searches among the *descendants* of the nodes in the array.

Because of this, you're needing to use both. `.filter()` to get the correct one at the top (`#posts`) and `.find()` to get the correct descendant (`.next`).

```
$(data).filter('#posts').find('.next');
```

This narrows the set down to only the `#posts` element, then finds the `.next` element that is a descendant.

Comment: You could onlineliner it even: `$('#container').append($('#posts', data));` --- Not that your example does this, but beware of calling `$(data)`/`$('#posts',data)` multiple times in this callback! That could potentially be a whole lot of unneeded processing/memory...

Comment: @gnarf - Actually `$("#posts", data).appendTo("#container");` would be less wasteful :)

Comment: @Nick - Doesn't jQuery just flip it around into an `.append()`? http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/manipulation.js#L445

Comment: @jAndy - That's a matter of opinion I think..."find `#posts` in data, append it to `#container`"...to me it's much *more* readable.  You think "get data, find posts in it, then find container, append posts you found earlier to it" is better somehow? :)

Comment: @patrick - Yep, I was replying to gnarfs version that creates an extra jQuery object on the end there.

Comment: @Nick - Yes, but it seems that jQuery creates the same jQuery object with `appendTo()` when it flips it around. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @patrick - On a single element it's doing this: `insert[original]( this[0]);`, inserting the DOM element (original == "append"), not having that extra jQuery object in the chain, it's references, `.prevObject`, etc, it's tossed ASAP once it has the DOM element.

Comment: @Nick: heh, I'd like `$(data).find('#posts').appendTo('#container');` just because of the confusing order otherwise.

Comment: @jAndy - That version works equally well, since `$("#posts", data)` is `$(data).find("#posts")` under the covers.  My point was more of "what's readable" depends on the programmer, I find all of these easy to discern.  That's not to say which is best for everyone, that varies, just that the more familiar you get, other permutations/formats become more readable as well.  Sit me down in front of a perl script and I'd call it unreadable ;)

Comment: @Nick - Just seems that `insert[original]( this[0]);` is equivalent to `$('#container').append($('#posts', data)[0]);` since `insert` is the selector for `.appendTo(selector)` wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: i tried `alert($data.find("#posts").html());` and `alert($("#posts", data).html());` both returned null. but `alert(data)` gives the correct output

Comment: @jiewmeng - Did you notice my code comment about using `.filter()`? If the element you want is at the top level, meaning it doesn't have a parent element in `data`, you'll need to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @jiewmeng - ...by the way, don't be confused by the conversation above. They are suggesting different forms of what is ultimately the same thing. It is just a discussion about practices/efficiency/readability. :o)

Comment: oh yes `filter()` works. but i am wondering why. when i alert data, the output is the whole HTML structure, `<html><head/><body>...` so it should be hierarchical and i shld be using find? ok i will post a more complete dump of what is output in `alert()` in the update above

Comment: btw, `nextHref = $data.filter("#pageNav .next").attr("href"); alert(nextHref);` does not seem to select anything ...

Comment: @jiewmeng - Yes, jQuery places the direct children of the `body` tag in the array of the jQuery object. Using the code you posted, the result is an array of 8 nodes (including text nodes), and `#posts` is one of them because it is a direct child of `body`. When you use `filter()` you are only testing against the top items in that array. This is why `.filter('#posts')` works, but `.filter('#posts .next')` doesn't. It is because `.next` is a descendant of `#posts`. You need to `.filter('#posts').find('.next')` in order to filter the set down to `#posts` and find its descendants.

Answer (score 3):

To append using load:

```
jQuery('#Posts').append( jQuery('<div>').load(...) );
```

This will append whatever you load into the #Posts element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("YadaYadaYada.php", function(dat) {
   $(dat).find("body > #posts").appendTo("#container");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try use $(this), something like :

```
<div id="result">Hello World </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
            $(this).load('templates/test2.html', function(result) {
                $('#result').append(result);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This would replace the contents of `document` with that page...you really don't want to do anything like this, he needs something other than `.load()` in this case.