# Using .append & .load to load a section of another page to target page

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, load, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace and trying to use `.append` and `.load` to first create an empty div (hence `.append`) and **then** insert my newsletter div and its contents from a "mother" page of my site into a number of other pages of my site (must be with JQuery, not PHP).  This is so that I only have to edit the mother element and the changes are then reflected in the other pages. Squarespace offers no help along these lines and I can't find anything in their question forum either.

Here's my code that I've tried to use by following the examples I've found at [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [load() but append data instead of replace](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-but-append-data-instead-of-replace) and the stackoverflow question [JQuery use .load() to append data instead of replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203035/jquery-use-load-to-append-data-instead-of-replace) but I must be doing something wrong still:

**Simple JQuery**

```
$(".content").first().before("<div id='newsletter-section'>Newsletter Signup</div>");
// the above is to create the target div
$("#newsletter-section").load("example.com/newsletter .content");
```

**Ajax**

```
$(".content").first().before("<div id='newsletter-section'>Newsletter Signup</div>");
// the above is to create the target div
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/newsletter',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var div = $('.content', $(html)).addClass('done');
        $('#newsletter-section').html(div);
    }
});
```

I've tried using the `.get` method:

```
$(".content").first().before("<div id='newsletter-section'>Newsletter Signup</div>");
// the above is to create the target div
$.get("https://www.ikingdesigns.com/newsletter",function(data) {
    var newsletter = $(data).filter(".content");
    $("#newsletter-section").append(newsletter);
});
```

And also using `.load` within `.append`:

```
$('.content').append($('<div id="newsletter-section">Newsletter Signup</div>').load('example.com/newsletter .content'));
```

Do I need an extra script already loaded on my site so that it works?
Here's a fiddle in case that helps

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

Loading the newsletter from the url inside the target section, and then a callback to initialize it via SS's lifecycle methods.

```
$(".content").first().before("<div id='newsletter-section'>Newsletter Signup</div>");

$('#newsletter-section').load('https://www.ikingdesigns.com/newsletter .newsletter-block', function(){
  var block = Y.one('.newsletter-block');
  window.Squarespace.initializeNewsletterBlock(block);
});
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work either :( Should I copy and paste the DOM, CSS and jQuery into a fiddle for you? Is there some permission thing with Squarespace that doesn't allow this kind of a data call?

Comment: I can already visit any page on your site, plug that code in and shows up immediately.. Add it to a test page, so I can check for other issues

Comment: Ah, apologies. It seems to be working now. The admin panel doesn't display it for some reason, but it renders on the visitor end :)
Care to explain why your option worked and the others don't? And where did you get the `.Squarespace` and `.initializeNewsletterBlock` from? Sorry if these are n00b questions

Comment: @KingDesigns the other methods were probably working, but you weren't able to see anything due to the lack of initialization – I just went with the simplest option.

The Lifecycle methods are used by the platform to render blocks and bind handlers, on page load. Because you're rendering a new block outside the standard loading cycle you need to manually trigger it.

There isn't much in the way of documentation, but this repo is a good place to start https://github.com/Squarespace/squarespace-core